# How to save and recover prior posts on a mailing list to Thunderbird inbox?

Tags: thunderbird, mailing-lists, mailman

I'm participating in a mailing list handled by **Mailman**.

As I entered it in, let's say, 20/02, I don't have on my inbox emails sent until 19/02.

This mailing list has an archive with many and many emails, that I can access, but it has a poor interface.

In other words, to read some email, I have to click on the date it was sent, and then read it post by post.

Is there a way to save these old emails on my inbox and recover them?

I use Thunderbird, but didn't find an extension that solve this problem for me.

Any tips?

Comment: Great question. There was one mailing list I was on a number of years ago where you could download their entire archive as an mbox. Definitely not common practice. Very few mailing list archives even have a search feature in my experience!

Comment: @fideli Yeah. I think all maillist shoud disponibilize its content on this (and another) formats, such that you could find what you want instead of re-send a topic that's already discussed.

Answer (score 3):

Mailman allows you to download archived messages through web interface. You basically download gzipped file for each month, extract it and put it in Thunderbird's folder.

All steps are nicely explained in article [Importing Mailing List Archives to Thunderbird](http://johnpoelstra.com/importing-mailing-list-archives-to-thunderbird/).